# Black areas in Fisheye lens corners

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera, fisheye

today I wanted to try if it is possible to make mini planets with Fisheye similar to this:
[image]

The problem I have is that when I try to render my test with any settings I will always get black corners like this:
[image]

My question is, **is there a way to get rid of those black corners directly in Blender and to fill it with the world scene?**

I was unable to find this problem in other questions or the answers are way too outdated

EDIT: If I just change the lens it won't fit the sphere into the camera (there will be higher objects at the edges of the sphere that have to be visible)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Fiheye Equisolid**, set **field of view** to 360 deg and zoom in using **Lens** setting:

[image]

If you want to distort the image at the edges, so that more background is shown, you can do it in compozitor like this:

[image]

You can also try to setup a custom lens shape using K0-K4 parameters. Some of parameters distort the lens so much so that double sky can be displayed:

[image]

Some parameters scales image at the edges:

[image]

Comment: so no other way? Because I already tried that and if I use this then I am unable to fit the plane/sphere into camera and if I want it to fit then there will always be some black corner... I have edited my question to show it